# swapping all values between two select boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have two select boxex which content should be swapped by a `change` event
so `select_default1` gets the content of `select_default2` and vice versa

```
<select name="select_default1" class="select_default1">
                    <option value="">choose Columns</option>
      <option value=" 1"> 1</option>
       <option value=" 2"> 2</option>
       <option value=" 3"> 3</option>
       <option value=" 4"> 4</option>
</select>
```

```
<select name="select_default1" class="select_default1">
                    <option value="">choose Columns</option>
      <option value=" a"> a</option>
       <option value=" b"> b</option>
       <option value=" c"> c</option>
</select>
```

My approach was to save the values of each select box into an array

```
   let default1_array = [];
        $("#id option").each(function()
        {  default1_array.push( $(this).val());

        });
```

and then change the values of each box with values saves in the array.

I was wandering if there is a way to do this task in less steps

Comment: you would of course need to save not just the values, but also the internal text if they're possibly different

Comment: you also haven't coded for any way to save the 'selected' option of the 'select'

Comment: Under what event should the swap happen?

Comment: so personally, I would recommend you at least consider if you want the 'selected' option to be preserved on the swap, and you can make the whole job quite a bit easier with jquery by just literally copying the children over

Comment: "Cleaner" is a very subjective description. Please [edit] your question to describe, in objective terms, what "cleaner" means to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a super simple example which does preserve the selected element. I copy the children from each element, then empty each element and copy in the other elements children. Then I copy over the value.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  const oneChildren = $('#1').children();
  const twoChildren = $('#2').children();
  
  const oneValue = $('#1').val();
  const twoValue = $('#2').val();
  
  $('#1').empty().append(twoChildren);
  $('#2').empty().append(oneChildren);
  
  $('#1').val(twoValue);
  $('#2').val(oneValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="1">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<button>change</button>
```